# Shell Scripting: Echo vs save to variable

Tags: shell

Why do these do different things?

```
ENTRY="banana#Apple"

HOST_ID=$ENTRY | awk -F '#' '{print $2}'
echo $HOST_ID

echo $ENTRY | awk -F '#' '{print $2}'
```

In the echo command, the data is displayed as expected.  In the save to variable command, the data is not, and the variable is left empty.

Comment: You need tell the shell that your `HOST_ID=...` version is intended to execute a command. just putting some command-looking text on there isn't enough. `var=$(command here)` or ``var=`command here` ``

Comment: Its helpful, BTW, if you mention *which* shell you are using, though the techniques in the answers here tend to work for bourne-type shells: `bash`, `sh`, `zsh`, `dash`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
HOST_ID=$ENTRY | awk -F '#' '{print $2}'
```

means this:

```
HOST_ID='banana#Apple' | awk -F '#' '{print $2}'
```

In other words, you're running two commands in separate subshells — `HOST_ID='banana#Apple'`, and `awk -F '#' '{print $2}'` — and piping the output of one to the other. This doesn't accomplish anything: `HOST_ID='banana#Apple'` produces no output, so the `awk` command gets no input, so it doesn't print anything. (And because of the subshells, even the `HOST_ID='banana#Apple'` part has no effect: it's setting that variable in a subshell, rather than in the parent shell that's running the overall command. So the value disappears almost immediately)

---

Instead, you want to write:

```
HOST_ID="$(echo "$ENTRY" | awk -F '#' '{print $2}')
```

or:

```
HOST_ID="$(awk -F '#' '{print $2}' <<< "$ENTRY")
```

or perhaps (if you're only ever expecting `$ENTRY` to have two fields):

```
HOST_ID="${ENTRY#*#}"
```